# Text align right only with CSS in UL LI

Tags: html, css

I have html:

```
<ul>
    <li><span>text</span><span>to right</span></li>
        <li><span>text2 text2 text2 </span><span>to right</span></li>
        <li><span>text3</span><span>to right</span></li>
        <li><span>text4</span><span>to right</span></li>
        <li><span>text5text5text5</span><span>to right</span></li>
</ul>
```

and css:

```
ul li {
    width: 300px;
    background-color: #ff9999;
}
```

i would like make text-align to right for all second span in li, but i can't modify html structure. I can only add class or id. Is possible to make with only CSS?

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ePcDq/)

Comment: Please show us an example output (a screenshot, a mockup or a jsfiddle). Because I don't understand exactly what you want.

Comment: replaced anchor tag with li

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could float them instead:

```
ul li span+span {
    float: right;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ePcDq/1/

Answer (score 1):

You can try with [:nth-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3anth-child) pseudo selector to select the second child i.e. span and can put your css.

```
ul li span:nth-child(2)
{
    float:right;
}
```

[Js Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ePcDq/2/)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a class to every second *span* and add to this class **float: right**.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a class to span e.g.

```
<span class='right'>to right</span
```

and define `right` class as

```
.right{
    float:right;
}
```

[See jsFiddle in action](http://jsfiddle.net/evsuY/)